# PreparedStatement executing successfully in oracle but throwing exception in Microsoft SQL

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have this below query that I execute using java PreparedStatement:

```
String dml=insert into users(name, addr, city, sex, dob) values(?,?,?,?,?);
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(dml);
stmt.setString(1,"abcd");
stmt.setString(2,"def");
stmt.setString(3,"ghij");
stmt.setString(4,"m");
stmt.setString(5,"1-Jan-1987");
stmt.executeQuery();
```

It executes successfully when the database is Oracle, but when the database is Microsoft SQL, then it throws an exception `"java.sql.SQLException: The executeQuery method must return a result set"`. Could someone please tell what is the issue here. Why is the same query executing successfully in oracle but not in microsft sql?

Comment: The surprise is that Oracle "works".

Comment: @duffymo - it's java - oracle has been working with it for years....

Comment: I understand it's Java.  I think Oracle should have required the use of executeUpdate in this case, too.

Comment: @duffymo - yup I agree - but like all things once a side effect is public it's very hard to change that behaviour for fear of breaking compatibility.

Comment: Agreed, Preet.  Poor driver implementation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is in the message - ExecuteQuery requires a result set. Use [executeUpdate](http://www.coderanch.com/t/301594/JDBC/java/Difference-between-execute-executeQuery-executeUpdate) instead.

From the above Link:

- **boolean execute()** Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which may be any kind of SQL statement.
- **ResultSet executeQuery()** Executes the SQL query in this PreparedStatement object and returns the ResultSet object generated by the query.
- **int executeUpdate()**  Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

the fact that it works on oracle is probably just a side effect which you've discovered cannot be relied upon.

Answer (score 4):

If you're performing an INSERT/UPDATE statement, you should be calling `stmt.executeUpdate()` rather than `stmt.executeQuery()`. I imagine there's a difference (though I don't know exactly what) between the Oracle and SQL Server drivers you're using that means that one works and the other one doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

try using the method executeUpdate instead of executeQuery.

since the query at hand is not a select-query, it fails. executeQuery is for select-queries, executeUpdate is for insert, delete and update-queries.

Answer (score 1):

There is the problem on `stmt.executeQuery();`

- `executeQuery()` is used for SELECT sql operation
- `executeUpdate()` is used for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE sql operation.

your query is for INSERT operation thus please use `stmt.executeUpdate();`

Answer (score 0):

This depends upon **driver** that are using and **underlying implementation of executeQuery() method**. While using Java Prepared statement the underlying implementation allow this but the driver of SQL server doesnot allow this.

Try to use correct method to execute insert statement like executeUpdate().

go trough this links:-

Sql server:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378540%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Oracle:- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/statement.html

Answer (score -1):

use `stmt.execute();` instead of `stmt.executeQuery();`

- `stmt.execute(); or executeUpdate();` for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE (etc.)
- `stmt.executeQuery();` for SELECT

Comment: Wow thanks Martin. I was not specific. But that's the actual idea